# Clone HDD damaged with other the same model

Tags: linux, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, repair, system-repair-disc

I have 2 Seagate USB3.0 2TB drives (formatted as fat32) of the same model. One of them has many errors, and needs to be repaired.

I've tried to copy the contents of the healthy disk to the damaged disk with

```
cat /dev/hd(healthy) >/dev/hd(damaged)
```

However, errors were reported during this job, and I aborted the task.

I don't need the data from my damaged DISK, because I want copy the data of the healthy disk to the damaged disk.

Could I use `dd` or `ddrescue` to copy the data?  Should I reformat the damaged disk?

Comment: Why did you copy the healthy disk to the damaged one? People usually do the opposite to recover their data *from* damaged disks. Did you try to repair the disk by overwriting it with "healthy" data?

Comment: What is "damaged"? If you have bad sectors or physical damage, you will be better off with the drive in the bin than trusting it with your data.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I dont need the data of damaged disk because is the same of healty hdd

Comment: @RadialApps Yes I think that have bad sectors, what could i do? I dont need the data of the damaged HDD... I need copy healty disk information to damaged disk

Comment: @Milor123, if you do have bad sectors, claim warranty if you have it. The disk wouldn't be of use for much longer.

Comment: @RadialApps where's your sense of adventure?

Comment: @RadialApps Ty dude, but I dont have warranty, it have 5 years old or more...

Comment: @Milor123, in that case, the easiest option you have is to erase (yeah, reformat) and dd it.

Comment: @RadialApps Ty dude, A fast format could work? o need slow format?, what should i use dd or ddsecure? thank you very much :D

Comment: ddrescue, I daresay. If you have bad sectors, then you will have unreadable files with dd. Go for a slow format.

Comment: @RadialApps, thank you very much dude, I'll try format it :D

Comment: `ddrescue` is supposed to continue its work in case of read errors. You will encounter *write* errors. I guess the process will exit like your `cat` did. Still you can give it a try. Please report how it went.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Ty bro, I'll tell you later :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot overwrite the bad sectors of the disk with healthy data.  The on-board firmware has logic to test, attempt to correct or redirect data from a damaged portion to a new location and mark the sector as bad.  A few bad sectors is not a big deal.  However if you have a lot of them, it's a sign the disk is failing.

A good read can be found here: http://www.howtogeek.com/173463/bad-sectors-explained-why-hard-drives-get-bad-sectors-and-what-you-can-do-about-it/

I recommend you contact the manufacturer for warranty replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Hard disk, damaged, out of warranty - take tiny Torx drivers, open the drive casing, remove the nice magnets from the seek mechanism (careful of your fingers), decide if the shiny platters would make a nice Holiday ornament, recycle whatever is left. Unless you don't like strong magnets...

Want to copy data from good drive? Buy (or scavenge, if you are happy with 5 year old drives) another good drive. Pointless to copy onto a known damaged/bad drive. Even if it "succeeds" it will probably have more errors in the near future, and there goes your copied data.